# Centos Stream 9 dnf yum upgrade error

Tags: centos, ssl, upgrade

When trying to upgrade Centos Stream 9 from terminal I get the error about weak SSL certificate, below is the output from terminal

```
$dnf check-update
```

CentOS Stream 9 - BaseOS                                                                                         0.0  B/s |   0  B     00:06
Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'baseos':

- Curl error (60): SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK for https://mirrors.centos.org/metalink?repo=centos-baseos-9-stream&arch=x86_64&protocol=https,http [SSL certificate problem: EE certificate key too weak]
  Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'baseos': Cannot prepare internal mirrorlist: Curl error (60): SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK for https://mirrors.centos.org/metalink?repo=centos-baseos-9-stream&arch=x86_64&protocol=https,http [SSL certificate problem: EE certificate key too weak]

Thanks for helping